Is there a way to get the fitted values from a darts ts model?
I am using the darts FFT model (https://unit8co.github.io/darts/) in python.
While fit() and predict() is straight forward, I am unable to find a way to get the fitted values. How do I do that?
I want to understand how well the model has fit the data.
